# Odoo 11 (Document type: sale.order.line, Operation: read)

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am facing strange issue on my Odoo 11 community. When i try to add order line in my existing quotation or sale order it give me access error **(Document type: sale.order.line, Operation: read)**.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWfmU.png)

But when i remove all order line then when I try to add order lines again I have no error. Every time I have to edit my quotation or Sale order and add new order line I have to delete all the existing order lines and add them again with the new one. This is troublesome when I have more than 5 order line because I have remember all of my previous order line.

Any help be appreciated.

Comment: It says that you have access rights only to read. Maybe in some module you installed security csv file restricting sale.order.line

Comment: @Chaban33 my problem is I am not allowed to just edit sale order and add new row to sale order line but i can add row without any access error when i edit sale order and then delete all the existing sale order line and add them again with new one. If it was security issue then i should have got the access error always when i tried to add any row to order line. 
but i can still add after deleting all the existng row and adding them back.